# How to launch a Xamarin forms from Android Activity

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

The question is how can I navigate to a xamarin form from an activity in Android
My entire project is in Xamarin Android but I must call a XAML (xamarin form) that is within the same project

I tried this ...
Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new         zxing_android.Resources.layout.Page2());

and also with this ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(zxing_android.Resources.layout.Page2));
StartActivity(intent);
```

In both cases it gives me an error

[image]

as seen in the image, I am trying to open Page2.axml from my Xamarin Android MainActivity

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't suggest you use the xaml in the xamarin.android project. It should be used in the cross platform project.

In the xamarin.android project, if you want show the contentpage, you can use refer to the xamarin.forms project and use the `FormsAppCompatActivity` to render the contentpage.

1. Install the `Xamarin.Forms` nuget package in your project. I installed the newest version and updated the `Xamarin.Google.Android.Material` nuget package to the newest version.
2. Create `Xamarin.Forms.Application` in the project

The App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="App3.App">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

The App.cs:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App3
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class App : Xamarin.Forms.Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            MainPage = new Page1();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** When I created the app.cs, it told me that the MainPage and resource can't be found. Close and reopen the project will resolve this.

3. Load the `Xamarin.Forms.Application` in the `FormsAppCompatActivity`:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace App3
{
    [Activity(Label = "Activity1",Theme = "@style/MainTheme.Base")]
    public class Activity1 : FormsAppCompatActivity
    {

            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
}
```

4. Go to the contentpage in the MainActivity:

```
Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
button.Click += delegate
{
    var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
    StartActivity(intent);  
};
```

And my project's structure:

[image]